# Changing the duration time of a toolip in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I am creating a tooltip using the following code;

```
metaData.attr = 'ext:qtip="This is my tooltip"';
```

This works perfect, but the tooltip doesn't stay open for very long.

Is there anything i can add to this statement to increase the time the tooltip stays open?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is tagged with `extjs4`. Your title says `ExtJS 3.4`. Which is it?

Comment: Whoops, I have removed the 4 tag .. Im using 3.4

Comment: @CodeCodeCodeCode Is this a `tooltip` for `renderer` of a grid column? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase time using parameter `dismissDelay` (ms) when register quicktip.

```
Ext.QuickTips.register({
    target: 'my-div',
    title: 'My Tooltip',
    text: 'This tooltip was added in code',
    width: 100,
    dismissDelay: 10000 // Hide after 10 seconds hover
});
```

Or you can simple override all quick tips in application.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.QuickTips.getQuickTip(), {
    dismissDelay: 10000
});
```

You can't add extra parameter to `metaData.attr = 'ext:qtip="This is my tooltip"';` to change dismiss delay.

Comment: Hey @norbeq ... Thanks for that, nice answer!